# WM_SYSCHAR event generated on pressing alphanumeric keys

Tags: c++, windows, events, printing, keyboard-events

Under what scenarios will a WM_SYSCHAR event be generated?

In my application's message loop I'm getting a WM_SYSCHAR event even though I'm only pressing the character keys. According to the documentation this event denotes the press of a system key which is either alt + [any character] or F10.

However, this is happening only when using a particular environment. Normally on pressing the character keys I am getting a WM_KEYDOWN followed by WM_CHAR. But when I install a software called "Fasoo DRM Client" the shortcut keys in my application stopped working. This application runs in background and it is a file based security solution that monitors certain file extensions. On debugging further I noticed that the WM_SYSCHAR event was being generated instead of WM_CHAR when this software is running in the background. Also this will happen only after I print from my application.

Further this only happens when the driver page(or preferences page) for the printer shows up for the printer. Disabling this software is not an option as it is a customer system and his company policy does not allow for this.

Could you share some thoughts on why WM_SYSCHAR event may get generated even though I did not press any alt or fn keys?

**Some info on the software: http://en.fasoo.com/site/fasoo_eng/filebasedsecurity/fasooenterprisedrm.do**